# Neo4j Cypher manual relationship index, APOC trigger and data duplication 2

Tags: indexing, neo4j, triggers, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Continuing with the following question [Neo4j Cypher manual relationship index, APOC trigger and data duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493806/neo4j-cypher-manual-relationship-index-apoc-trigger-and-data-duplication) I have created the scenario which reproduces the issue:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('TEST_TRIGGER', "UNWIND keys({assignedRelationshipProperties}) AS key 
UNWIND {assignedRelationshipProperties}[key] AS map 
WITH map 
WHERE type(map.relationship) = 'LIVES_IN' 
CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(map.relationship, keys(map.relationship)) 
RETURN count(*)", {phase:'before'})

CREATE (p:Person) SET p.id = 1 return p
CREATE (p:Person) SET p.id = 2 return p
CREATE (c:City) return c

MATCH (p:Person), (c:City) WHERE p.id = 1 CREATE (p)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c) SET r.time = 10 RETURN type(r)
MATCH (p:Person), (c:City) WHERE p.id = 2 CREATE (p)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c) SET r.time = 20 RETURN type(r)
```

Now, let's try to select the person with `r.time = 10`:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) 
CALL apoc.index.in(c, 'LIVES_IN', 'time:10') YIELD node AS person 
RETURN person
```

The query above correctly returns only one node.

Now, let's do the same but return the `person` count:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) 
CALL apoc.index.in(c, 'LIVES_IN', 'time:10') YIELD node AS person 
RETURN count(person)
```

The query above returns `count = 2`.

Why this query returns `count = 2` instead of the single node?

Also, the following query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) 
CALL apoc.index.relationships('LIVES_IN', 'time:10') YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

returns 2 relationships:

```
{
  "time": 10
}
{
  "time": 10
}
```

but I expect only the single one in the manual index where `time = 10`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query in your example returns also two lines. Apparently you look at the result in the form of a graph. Try or switch to table mode, or change the query for this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City) 
CALL apoc.index.in(c, 'LIVES_IN', 'time:10') YIELD node AS person 
RETURN ID(person)
```

Two lines are obtained because you have two people living in the same city and for each relationship you do a search on the index. Try this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City)
WITH DISTINCT c
CALL apoc.index.in(c, 'LIVES_IN', 'time:10') YIELD node AS person 
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT person)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have two people living in the same city but only one of them with time=10 so I don’t understand why 2 results are returned instead a single one. Could you please comment on this?

Comment: Because you first get a city for each person, and then you do an index search for the same city as many times as there are persons living in this city.

Comment: Well.. how about the last query in my question with apoc.index.relationships ? I don’t use city there. Why it also returns 2 same relationships instead a single one?

Comment: Because the search for the index after this pattern `MATCH (p:Person)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:City)` is called twice - think of it as a loop. And neo4j does not automatically remove duplicates from the result.

Comment: Thanks. The core issue - I’d like to replace filtering based on pure relationship properties, for example WHERE r.time=10 with manual indexes. So, is it a good idea to use DISTINCT there with apoc.index.* queries in case I’ll have tens or hundreds of thousands nodes?

Comment: DISTINCT still need to be applied. Look, by the way, I made changes to the second query - the distinct is applied twice.

Answer (score 1):

Just your query example is wrong, use this:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('LIVES_IN', 'time:10') YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

or this

```
MATCH (c:City) 
CALL apoc.index.in(c, 'LIVES_IN', 'time:10') YIELD node AS person 
RETURN count(person)
```